# Setting up a adhoc wifi network with nmtui does not work

Tags: wireless, network-manager, 22.10, adhoc

I want to make an adhoc network to do stuff I guess
heres nmtui
[image]

nmcli
[image]

[journelctl log](https://pastebin.com/rcA4hPZV)

wifi info airmon-ng output
`phy0    wlp2s0          iwlwifi         Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)`

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612498/hotspot-network-creation-took-too-long-and-failed-activation

Comment: wired thing the hotspot button in the kde wifi menu works

Comment: @Andra I tried that and it did not work